# can someone explain to me this command (make ARCH)?

Tags: android, linux, build, makefile

```
make ARCH=arm msm_defconfig
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$SOURCE_FOLDER/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi- zImage -j4
```

I would like to build android kernel, and I did find some tutorial on that. and I found the command above, I want to know how this command work? So if someone can explain it or give me some references on this, that will be better.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make ARCH=arm` will specify that this is an intended build for the ARM architecture since you are cross-compiling on a non-ARM system. `CROSS_COMPILE` is specifying the name to append to tools so that the correct tools are used to generate your resulting object files and binaries.

`ARCH=arm` is actually a local environment variable (for lack of the official term) - you could have set it as an environment variable. Same thing with `CROSS_COMPILE`

```
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE="..."
make -j4 zImage
```

Though if you did that, you might affect your environment for all `make` commands executed.

**edit** The only resource that seemed useful in explaining those two flags to any extent, as everyone else basically says to copy what they do without fully explaining it: http://book.opensourceproject.org.cn/embedded/oreillybuildembed/opensource/belinuxsys-chp-5-sect-3.html

Comment: do you mean I have to choose right toolset according to my compiling platform, like this "$SOURCE_FOLDER/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-" right ?

Comment: @MemoryLeak - the `arm-eabi-` portion will be appended to tool names, so for example the `gcc` compiler to use will be `arm-eabi-gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters to `make` with a `=` are converted to variables within the makefile. `-j` tells make to run multiple parallel processes to handle the build. The remaining argument is the build target. See both `Makefile` in the current directory as well as the GNU make documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the -j parameter.